# Open file in vertical split in Vim / netrw

Tags: vim, netrw

If I open vim with `vim .` netrw provides me with a nice list of the files and directories in the current directory.

If I open a file using `v` the file opens in a very narrow split down the left hand side of the screen and the directory listing remains open in a wide split on the right hand side of the screen.

Ideally I'd like it to have the opposite effect, that is, to show the directory listing in a narrow split on the left hand side of the screen and show the file in a wide split on the right hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure this could be improved upon you can write a custom mapping that target's the `netrw` filetype.

Stick this in your `.vimrc`:

```
" open file vertically to the right
augroup netrw_mappings
    autocmd!
    autocmd filetype netrw call Netrw_mappings()
augroup END
function! OpenToRight()
  :rightbelow vnew
  :wincmd p
  :normal P
endfunction
function! Netrw_mappings()
    noremap V :call OpenToRight()<cr>
endfunction
```

The only thing is that you need to use `V` rather than `v`. For some reason I was unable to override `netrw`'s `v` command, but using the capital version seems better anyway since it's not overriding a default.

Comment: That's fantastic! - Sorry to be cheeky but... is it possible to control the width's of the splits?

Comment: @jx12345 You can run commands like `:30winc >` to change the window width

Comment: nnoremap <buffer> v :call OpenToRight()<cr> will do add `<buffer>`

Answer (score 28):

Netrw v153 and later (May 28, 2014) gives you the `:Lexplore` command, which, by default, opens a directory listing on the left hand side and opens files to the right (by pressing `<cr>`).

Comment: That looks perfect, thanks.. Could you give me a hint as to how / where to install the new version... Do I need to uninstall the existing netrw?

Answer (score 11):

Whilst Jonathan.Brink's answer works perfectly well, simply adding

```
let g:netrw_altv=1
```

to .vimrc also seems to do the trick...

See https://superuser.com/questions/1056929/open-file-in-vertical-split-in-vim-netrw/1062063#1062063 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your .vimrc, it works well with `v`

set splitright

By default, the netrw plugin follows your splitright setting (as indicated by its default value =&spr for the g:netrw_altv variable) when deciding where to open new windows.

I think that netrw reads the value of splitright at Vim's startup. So, setting splitright using `:set splitright` in a session won't affect netrw's behavior in that session.